# Can i get ADS certificate via Java LDAP search

Tags: java, ldap, certificate

I am able to find out the exact cn of the certificate of my `ADS server`.  Is there a way to download it as a abc.cer via Java LDAP API, which I can then import via keytool to my cacerts?

Also, I only can bind myself to the directory context for this download, will this certificate be legitimate when I try to bind as someone else (to authenticate them, of course)?

I got the certicate cn by searching with base of `'cn=configuration,dc=mydomain'`
and filter of `'cacertificate=*'` and scope of 2 (subtree).

Many thanks.
Do Do

Answer (score 0):

U can use InstallCert (https://github.com/escline/InstallCert) application for connecting throught ssl with your server, and automatically downloaded the server certificate. This app, gets your cacerts file(truststore) and add there the one it has download. It generates a file called "jssecacerts".
Then  you just use KeystoreExplorer for openning and getting info of your certificate.

For running correctly Installcert, you have to add the next params to your java run configuration:

> host:port password

Password by default use to be "changeit"